# GCP Workflows with BigQuery: ResourceLimitError: Memory usage limit exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have some input tables on a BigQuery dataset and need to perform around 15 different SQL queries and store the result into a new BigQuery dataset. Queries are usually heavy (up to 10 GiB).

To connect Workflows with BigQuery, the only way I found is an HTTP-​based API called BigQueryConnector. There is 3 main connectors and the one I am using is the [insert](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/bigquery/v2/jobs/insert) one but I am getting this error after 30-40 run:

```
ResourceLimitError: Memory usage limit exceeded
```

Code:

```
- init:
    assign:
    - project_id: "abc"
    - dataset_id: "test_360_pipe"
    - table_id: "table_1"
    - query: |
        SELECT 
        SourceSystem_txt  AS sourceSystem,
        TransactionNumber AS transaction_number,
        FROM `abc.bqdts_datalake_vault_sales_vc.bqvw_transactions_customers`
    - create_disposition: "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"  # create a new one if table doesn't exist
    - write_disposition: "WRITE_TRUNCATE"  # truncate it if the table already exists

- insert_table_into_dataset:
    call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.insert
    args:
      projectId: ${project_id}
      body:
        configuration:
          query:
            query: ${query}
            destinationTable:
              projectId: ${project_id}
              datasetId: ${dataset_id}
              tableId: ${table_id}
            create_disposition: ${create_disposition}
            write_disposition: ${write_disposition}
            allowLargeResults: true
            useLegacySql: false
    result: insertResult
    
- init2:
    assign:
    - project_id: "abc"
    - dataset_id: "test_360_pipe"
    - table_id: "table_2"
    - query: |
        SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `abc.test_360_pipe.table_1`
    - create_disposition: "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"  # create a new one if table doesn't exist
    - write_disposition: "WRITE_TRUNCATE"  # truncate it if the table already exists

- insert_table_into_dataset2:
    call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.insert
    args:
      projectId: ${project_id}
      body:
        configuration:
          query:
            query: ${query}
            destinationTable:
              projectId: ${project_id}
              datasetId: ${dataset_id}
              tableId: ${table_id}
            create_disposition: ${create_disposition}
            write_disposition: ${write_disposition}
            allowLargeResults: true
            useLegacySql: false
    result: insertResult
- the_end:
    return: ${insertResult}
```

Comment: The same workflow fails after 30 or 40 executions, correct? And how do you fix that? You redeploy a new workflow version? and then wait again for 30 - 40 executions until it fails?

Comment: Yes, and to be honest most of the INSERT jobs are failing. I am wondering if I should switch to another GCP product...

Comment: Bigquery insert should create too large answer for Workflow (the variable memory is limited, and you can have a memory usage limit exceeded in this case, but it happens when you get data from BigQuery. In your case you only create a job that copy data from a query to a destination table.) You should open a case to the support. And YES it's the correct product for that

Comment: hello @Pierre-Alexandre, just wanted to know if this was taken up with google support? Just wanted to know how was this handled?

Comment: Hi, nope, I moved to Airflow. I think Workflows in not that great to handle large pipeline with the BQ connector

Comment: This is a known bug in Workflows when invoking a bigquery connector: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183100019